# How to update model by id in Backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js

I've tried simple example from backbone tutorial and can't get this working

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person,
    url: "http://localhost:3002/people"
});

var people = new People();

var person = new Person({
    id: 3
});

person.fetch({
    success: function () {
        person.set({age: 23});
        person.save();
    }
});
```

I just want to update existing record with id equals to 3 but got an error **A "url" property or function must be specified**. I'm sure that I didn't make mistake when typing this example but it works in tutorial and doesn't work for me. Is it because of some version changes?

Comment: Can you post a link to the mentioned tutorial?

Comment: You create the model outside of the collection using fetch. So the model is not associated with the collection. You have to either use the collection to read/save or set the URL for the model.

Comment: Your person is not associated with your collection in any way. It has no idea what its URL is.

Comment: Your model does not have an url property only your collection has one. But you're not fetching the collection you're fetching the model

Comment: @nemesv It's a video tutorial, I don't have link to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error and comments have indicated, you need to specify the `url` property for the model or add the `person` model the `people` collection.

If you would like to `fetch` your model using the same `url` as the `people` collection. You need to add `person` to the `people` collection by doing:

```
var people = new People(person);

// or 

people.add(person);

// The fetch url for a person would look like
// GET http://localhost:3002/people/3       Assuming the id of the person is 3.
```

If you need to use a different `url` than your collection has specifed the `person` model. You can specify the `url` or `urlRoot` attribute in your `Person` model.

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot:'http://localhost:3002/person'
});

// The fetch url for a person would look like
// GET http://localhost:3002/person/3       The number will match id of model.
```